# Return word specified by the integer

Tags: java, string, methods, indexof

I know I'm missing some things and that's what I really need help with. The code doesn't work in all cases and am looking for help improving/fixing it.

Assignment:

[image]

The code I have so far:

```
public String word(int num, String words)
{
    int l = words.indexOf(" ");
    int r = words.indexOf(" ", l+1);

    for(int i = 3; i <= num; i++){


     l = r;
     r = words.indexOf(" ", l+1);

    //if(i != num)
//  l = r;

    }       
String theword = words.substring(l,r);
    return theword;


}
}
```

Comment: You should post the code here rather than in an image.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String- you should look into the split() method

Comment: what cases isn't it working in?

Comment: split the word first, it'll give you an array, then just return the element in the position given -1 ('cause array are 0 - index) first you have to check if the number given >= array.length and return  null in that case.

Comment: I'm trying to do it without the split method since I didn't learn it in my class yet

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For the first problem, I'll give you two approaches (1. is recommended):

1. Use the [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method to split the words up into an *array* of words, where each element is a word. Instead of one string containing all of the words, such as `"hello my name is Michael"`, it will create an array of the words, like so `[hello, my, name, is, Michael]` and that way you can use the array to access the words. Very easy:

   ```
   public static String word(int num, String words)
   {
       // split words string into array by the spaces
       String[] wordArray = words.split(" "); // or = words.split("\\s+");

       // if the number is within the range
       if (num > 0 && num <= wordArray.length) {
           return wordArray[num - 1]; // return the word from the word array
       } else { // the number is not within the range of words
           return null;
       }
   }
   ```
2. **Only use this if you cannot use arrays!** Loop through the word until you have found enough spaces to match the word you want to find:

   ```
   public static String word(int num, String words)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < words.length(); i++) { // every character in words
           if (words.substring(i, i+1).equals(" ")) { // if word is a space
               num = num - 1; // you've found the next word, so subtract 1 (number of words left is remaining)
           }
           if (num == 1) { // found all words
               // return this word
               int lastIndex = i+1;
               while (lastIndex < words.length()) { // until end of words string
                   if (words.substring(lastIndex, lastIndex+1).equals(" ")) {
                       break;
                   }
                   lastIndex = lastIndex + 1; // not a space so keep moving along the word
               }
               /*
               // or you could use this to find the last index:
               int lastIndex = words.indexOf(" ", i + 1); // next space after i+1
               if (lastIndex == -1) { // couldn't find another space
                   lastIndex = words.length(); // so just make it the last letter in words
               }*/
               if (words.substring(i, i+1).equals(" ")) { // not the first word
                   return words.substring(i+1, lastIndex);
               } else {
                   return words.substring(i, lastIndex);
               }
           }
       }
       return null; // didn't find word
   }
   ```

As for the second problem, just iterate *backwards* through the string and add each letter to a new string. You add each letter from the original string to a new string, but just back to front. And you can use [`String.toUpperCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase%28%29) to convert the string to upper case. Something like this:

```
public static String reverse(String str) {
    String reversedString = ""; // this will be the reversed string

    // for every character started at the END of the string
    for (int i = str.length() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        // add it to the reverse string
        reversedString += str.substring(i, i+1);
    }
    return reversedString.toUpperCase(); // return it in upper case
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As this is clearly homework, I will give you text only.

Your approach may work eventually, but it is laborious and overly complicated, so it's hard to debug and hard to get right.

- make use of String's API by using the `split()` method
- after splitting the sentence into an array of word Strings, return the element at `num` less one (array are indexed starting at zero
- check the length of the array first, in case there are less words than `num`, and take whatever action you think is appropriate in that case

For part 2, a solution in a simple form may be:

- create a new blank string for the result
- iterate over the characters of the given string adding the character to the *front* of the result string
- make use of String's `toUpperCase()` method

Comment: Could you add a similar hint for part 2 for a complete answer please? Like, say, a good class whose API would make the problem easy?

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of StringBuilder.reverse() to avoid code-point issues, but I guess that will do.

Comment: I've given you an algorithm. As for class design, consider what it is that your class does, and provide methods for those actions. Since the methods do not require state (there is no effect on the class when calling it), the methods can and should be `static`.

Comment: @Ordous Yes, StringBuilder would be better, but I was giving you the simplest thing I could think if as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is homework and you have showed some effort. This is how you can do part 1 of your question. This code is pretty evident.

1) I am returning null if number is greater than the number of words in string as we dont want user to enter 5 when there are only 2 words in a string
2) Splitting the string by space and basically returning the array with the number mentioned by user

There are more conditions which you must figure out such as telling the user to enter a number of the string length since it would not give him any result and taking input from `Scanner` instead of directy adding input in method.

```
public static String word(int num, String words)
{
  String wordsArr[] = words.split(" ");

  if(num <= 0 || num > wordsArr.length) return null;

  return (wordsArr[num-1]);

}
```

the second part of your question must be attempted by you.

Comment: It takes talent to make a mistake here. In your solution you return null if the integer is larger than the number of LETTERS not words.

Comment: Still wrong, you got an off by one error, check the condition in the brackets.

Comment: Still wrong! Your check is correct, but the return isn't. The problem specifies that words are counted from 1, yet java arrays are from 0

Comment: Also the problem allows to take any integer, not just positive ones, for a complete academic answer you need to check the lower bound on the int as well.

Comment: I did not put all code for those conditions as you mentioned as this is a homework and I will be doing it for him. But your points must be considered and I am going to edit my answer with your suggestions

Comment: Well the lower bound I can understand, that's a minor point. But returning the wrong word is a bad error(

Comment: @Ordous Tested my code but check if I missed any other test cases.

Comment: I reversed my downvote after the last edit, I think it's correct now

Answer (score 0):

Well... not often you see people coming here with homework AND showing effort at the same time so bravo :).

This is example of how you can split the string and return the [x] element from that string

```
public class SO {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int number = 3;
        String word = "Hello this is sample code"; 

        SO words = new SO();
        words.returnWord(number, word);
    }
    private void returnWord(int number, String word) throws Exception {
        String[] words = word.split("\\s+");
        int numberOfWords = words.length;

        if(numberOfWords >= number) {
            System.out.println(words[number-1]);
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Not enought words!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

Yes it is a working example but do not just copy and paste that for your homework - as simple question from teacher - What is this doing, or how this works and your out :)! So understand the code, and try to modify it in a way that you are familiar what is doing what. Also its worth getting some Java book - and i recommend Head first Java by O'Really <- v.good beginner book!

if you have any questions please do ask!. Note that this answer is not 100% with what the textbook is asking for, so you can modify this code accordingly.

As of part 2. Well what Bohemian said will also do, but there is a lot quicker solution to this.

Look at [StringBuilder()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html); there is a method on it that will be of your interest.
To convert String so all letter are upper case you can use .toUpperCase() method on this reversed string :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
    public class trial {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            System.out.println(specificword(0, "yours faithfully kyobe"));
            System.out.println(reverseString("derrick"));}
        
        public static String specificword(int number, String word){
            //split by space
            String [] parts = word.split("\\ ");
            if(number <= parts.length){
                return parts[number];
            }
            else{
                return "null String";
            }
        }
    
        public static String reverseString(String n){
            String c ="";
            for(int i = n.length()-1; i>=0; i--){
                char m = n.charAt(i);
                c = c + m;
            }
            String m = c.toUpperCase();
            return m;
        }
    }
```